# How to deal with repeated code when using if ... else statements?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a function like:

```
    validateUserFile(invalid: boolean) {
        this.validUser = !invalid;
        if (this.validUser) {
            this.getUserInfo().subscribe(userInfo => {
                const inclompleteFile = !!userInfo;
                if (incompleteFile) {
                    this.checkContinueRegistration(userInfo);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

And this function:

```
    advance() {
        if (this.validUser) {
            this.getUserInfo().subscribe(userInfo => {
                const inclompleteFile = !!userInfo;
                if (incompleteFile) {
                    this.checkContinueRegistration(userInfo);
                }
            });
        } else {
          this.goNextPage();
    }
```

Those functions are almost equal, with the difference that the second one has a `else` statement which leads the user to the next page. They are triggered from different sources. I tried to figure out a way to make this code cleaner and with less repetition but I couldn't come with a solution. Is this bad code or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The `this.validUser = !invalid;` looks to be a difference too?

Comment: Yes, there's that difference too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the logic above revolves if there is a parameter passed or not and perform those different logics, you can implement this way instead:

```
validate(invalid?: boolean) {
   if (invalid !== undefined) this.validUser = !invalid;

   if (this.validUser) this.getUserInfo().subscribe(user => !!user ? this.checkContinueRegistration(userInfo) : null);
   else if (invalid === undefined && !this.validUser) this.goNextPage();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd make more sense to do this in the *caller*. Stick with your original code except without the `invalid` check, and instead of calling `advance`, do:

```
if (invalid) {
  this.goNextPage();
} else {
  this.validateUserFile();
}
```

Similarly, instead of calling

```
this.validateUserFile(invalid)
```

, do

```
this.validUser = !invalid;
if (!invalid) {
  this.validateUserFile();
}
```

You could also have a single function that accepts a second `advanceIfInvalid` parameter that you check in the `else`, but handling this in the caller seems better.

Comment: Sorry. I forgot to remove the params from `advance()`. So, I can't call `validateUserFile` without params.

Comment: i can't replace `advance`with your code because `invalid` is a param given only to `validateUserFile`.

Comment: Like the answer says, change `validateUserFile` so that it doesn't check for `invalid` or use it - do that stuff in the caller instead.